# How to make dictionary of list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have below code:

```
for i in range(len(known_embeddings["embeddings"])):
    known_vec = known_embeddings["embeddings"][i]
    vec = vec.reshape(-1, 1)
    distance = cv2.norm(vec, known_vec)
    print("name : {}, distance : {}".format(known_embeddings["names"][i], distance))
```

In above code `known_embeddings` is dict of list which contains `embeddings` and `names` as list. The output of above code is :

```
name : mark, distance : 0.8483050632128444
name : mark, distance : 0.8724386372273983
name : mark, distance : 0.7805887577479304
name : mark, distance : 1.1670809288281123
name : mark, distance : 0.7298390620115697
name : tom, distance : 0.8128083541249622
name : tom, distance : 1.1103164155361172
name : tom, distance : 1.0548001777991225
name : tom, distance : 1.265357138869811
name : tom, distance : 1.2954636861331879
```

where each name contains a value of distance. Now I want to save above result into a dict of list or may be two different list so that I can later compare the values of each index of both the names. How can I save it in dict of list.? Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output, please add an example to make it clear. Is known_embeddings sorted by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty of simplifying a bit your code. Please try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
vec = vec.reshape(-1, 1)

for name, embedding in zip(known_embeddings["names"], known_embeddings["embeddings"]):
    distance = cv2.norm(vec, embedding)
    d[name].append(distance)
```

Because you have multiple values (distances) for the same key (name), we need to append them to a list, and [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) comes in handy just for that, for initializing each key with an empty list so it's safe to append values to it..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the loop that ends with

```
print("name : {}, distance : {}".format(known_embeddings["names"][i], distance))
```

try this:

```
my_dictionary = {knownembeddings["names"][i] : cv2.norm(vec.reshape(-1, 1), known_embeddings["embeddings"][i]) for i in range(len(known_embeddings["embeddings"]))}
```

Comment: Beware, this doesn't solve the problem. Notice that the keys are duplicated, with this solution, you'll only store the last occurrence of the value. We need to build a _list_ for the values.